# Why environment variable disappears after terminal reopen?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I've tryed to add environment variable in terminal:

```
loom@loom:~$ export DOOM=/home/loom/doom/
loom@loom:~$ echo $DOOM 
bash: /home/loom/doom/: Is a directory
```

Then I've closed terminal and reopened it. However, there isn't `$DOOM` variable now. How to add environment variable via terminal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Environment variables set like this are only stored temporally. When you exit the running instance of bash by exiting the terminal, they get discarded.
To save them permanentally, write the `export x=y` commands into `/etc/profile` (for all users) or `~/.profile` (for yourself)
Do this by editing/creating (?) the file using your preferred text editor (as root for /etc/profile). Examples:

```
sudo nano /etc/profile
gedit ~/.profile
# etc... kate, leafpad, vim, whatever you want to use
```

Comment: Better to use `~/.bashrc` file instead `~/.profile` file!

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: Please see [.profile vs. .bash_profile vs. .bashrc](http://serverfault.com/questions/261802/profile-vs-bash-profile-vs-bashrc)

Comment: @RaduRădeanu: I don't understand what you base your claim on that ~/.bashrc is better than ~/.profile. Environment variables set in ~/.bashrc are not available in graphical shells. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables